# Event log write error

Tags: c#, .net

It is simple, I want to write something to event log.

```
protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // TODO: Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("IvrService"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                "IvrService", "IvrServiceLog");
        }
        EventLog eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
        eventLog1.Source = "IvrService";
        eventLog1.Log = "IvrServiceLog";
        try
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Successfully "+State.Stopped.ToString());
            IvrApplication.StopImmediate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The exception is:

```
   Failed to stop service. System.ArgumentException: The source 'IvrService' is not   registered in log 'IvrServiceLog'. (It is registered in log 'Application'.) " The Source   and Log properties must be matched, or you may set Log to the empty string, and it will automatically be matched to the Source property.
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.VerifyAndCreateSource(String sourceName, String currentMachineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String message)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong.  You have the Event Source `IvrService` registered with the Application Log, not the IvrServiceLog.  The `System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists` verifies that the source exists, but not for a particular log.

My guess is that you originally registered this with the Application log and then later changed it to write to the `IvrServiceLog`.

To clean up your development machine, you could simply run the following and then you code should work going forward.

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.DeleteEventSource("IvrService");
```

Comment: @Love Yeah, you should just have to run the code I posted once on your development machine to cleanup the existing logs and then it should work going forward.

Comment: You are right, but in my case when I run the code which deletes the event source, my service runs fine, but I have always to delete the event source, not only once. The problem is that I have one entry in the Application event (maybe I created this starting the service as an application), and this can not be deleted. The only solution I found was to change the event source name.

Comment: Could you edit the answer to include that the powershell cmdlet [Remove-EventLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1) is able to delete the source as well with the `-Source` flag. Thanks btw.

Comment: I'm seeing another technically correct but equally unhelpful error message when attempting to use Remove-EventLog: "The event log source 'X' cannot be deleted, because it's equal to the log name."